# Key event doesn't work correctly in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, asp.net

On my web site I have the ability for users to use search by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, having typed a string in the search input field. Here is some jQuery code to illustrate this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#search-input').on('keydown keyup keypress', function (event) {
        event = event || windows.event;
        if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.which == 13) {
            $("#search-button").click();
        }
    });

    $("#search-button").click(function () {
        var theUrl = "/search.aspx?search=" + document.getElementById('search-input').value;
        window.location = theUrl;
    });
}
```

On my master page I have the following code:

```
<input id="search-input" name="search" type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
<button id="search-button" type="button"></button>
```

Although this works in FireFox and IE9/IE8, it doesn't work in Chrome (except when in debug mode which is surprising). Please help me make it work correctly in all of these browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Stop complicating things by binding multiple events, as `keypress` and `keyup` don't always return the same values, and the function will be called multiple times, once for each event triggered. Also, `e.which` is normalized in jQuery, and again you're complicating it too much:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#search-button").on('click', function() {
         var theUrl = "/search.aspx?search=" + $('#search-input').val();
         window.location = theUrl;
    });
    $('#search-input').on('keyup', function(e) {
         if (e.which == 13) 
            $("#search-button").trigger('click');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your code is truly cross-browser and helped to solve my problem. Users will be redirected only if they press enter key at the field.

Comment: Duh! I was'nt really thinking, and forgot about the nr.13 key if condition, so of course it's okay like that! With jQuery, just sticking with the basics often works the best.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any JavaScript for this.

```
<form method="GET" action="/search.aspx">
    <input name="search" type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Unless you specifically wanted the form to not work with javascript disabled.